# Свойство IsEnabled у Button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Свойство `IsEnabled` у `Button` я привязываю к свойству своего класса булевского типа `IsChecked`. Но я хочу, чтобы кнопка была доступна для нажатия, когда свойство `IsChecked = false`. Для этого я перед свойством `IsChecked` добавляю знак отрицания. Кнопка становится доступной, так как начальное значение `IsChecked = false`, при нажатии же это значение меняется на `true`, но при этом кнопка все равно остается доступной для нажатия. В чем проблема? Почему свойство IsEnabled не меняется при изменении свойства IsChecked?

```
  <Button
          Command="{Binding Activate}" 
          Width="25" 
          Height="25"
          IsEnabled="{Binding !IsChecked }"/>
```

Comment: а кто сказал, что знак отрицания работает?

Comment: Ваше "...свойству своего класса булевского типа..." выдает событие `PropertyChanged` ? Если нет, то UI и кнопка в частности ничего не знают об изменении в свойстве. Да, я не уверен, что `!` сработает как надо, для такого изменения значения нужен конвертер.

Comment: @Monk без знака отрицания кнопки недоступны,а со знаком доступны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете использовать оператор `!` в привязке. Вместо этого вам нужно определить конвертер значений или использовать триггер данных (`DataTrigger`):

```
    <Style x:Key="notEnabled" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

и

```
    <Button 
            Command="{Binding Activate}"
            Style="{StaticResource notEnabled}" />
```

Comment: а куда вписывать строчки <Style>...</Style>?

Comment: @Draktharon, Туда, где вы храните ресурсы